# Output does not show new lines in PHP

Tags: php

You all might say this is a foolish question submitted here but can anyone give any valid reason for the output I am getting. This is amazing and strange because "\n" forgot its work. I am getting this output

> Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test

for this code:

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
{
    echo "TEST \n";
    echo "TEST"."\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at it in HTML; in HTML, new lines are treated like regular spaces. Look at the source for the page and you will see the new lines there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want output in new line try this...

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
{
    echo "TEST </br>"; 
    echo "TEST </br>";
}

?>
```